# Which MongoDB Driver for Node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

The choices are over whelming. I looked at Mongoose and didn't like b/c I don't want I should have to model data when using Mongo. Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 18):

There is really only one node.js [MongoDB driver](https://github.com/christkv/node-mongodb-native).

There are several other tools that sit on top of this driver.

- [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) is an ORM tool, but completely unnecessary.
- You may want to take a look at [Mongoskin](https://github.com/guileen/node-mongoskin) or [Mongolia](https://github.com/masylum/mongolia) which provide less verbose access than the "native" driver.

Good list of MongoDB/Node.JS tools [here](http://toolbox.no.de/search?q=mongodb).

Comment: So this is an 18-month old post and Mongoose has been through several revs since writing this post. That stated, the OP states that he wants to avoid forced modeling via Mongoose, I am pointing out that all you really need is the underlying driver. This is kind of like saying that you don't need Hibernate to access MySQL. You are free to drop down to the driver level and write commands directly.

Answer (score 1):

Then you may want to use node.js' [native mongodb driver](https://github.com/christkv/node-mongodb-native), which is the underlying driver upon which mongoose is built. You can also search on [the npm registry](http://search.npmjs.org/) for more options.

Answer (score 1):

Correct nodejs mongodb driver as of 2019 :

> *The official MongoDB driver for Node.js*
>   https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native